# Why doesn't JTable update its view when adding new rows to DefaultTableModel?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, swingworker

I have weird problems with JTable. Method `addRows` doesn't force `jTable` to update its view:

```
public class VirusTable extends JTable {

    private String[] columnNames = { "", "Virus", "Path", "Size", "Created", "Last Mofified" };

    DefaultTableModel tableModel;

    public VirusTable() {
        super();

        tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) super.getModel();
        tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);

        // super.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        // super.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(5, 5));
        // super.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
        // super.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
    }

    public void addRows(Collection<UserFile> viruses) {
        System.out.println("AddRows=" + viruses);

        for (UserFile virus : viruses) {
            tableModel.addRow(virus.toRowData());
        }
//      tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
        // tableModel.fireTableStructureChanged();
        int rowCount = super.getRowCount();
//      super.revalidate();
//      super.repaint();
        System.out.println("rowCount=" + rowCount);
    }
}
```

`addRows` method is called from `SwingWorker.process` method.
Interestingly that `rowCount` is always correct but rows are not displayed on `JTable`.

I tried everything and nothing helps.
I wanted to create short runnable demo but I cannot implement this bug.

I posted this project [on github](https://github.com/volodiaL/Antivirus) and described what is wrong there.

Comment: If you cannot implement the bug in a short demo then perhaps the bug is occurring elsewhere?

Comment: Can you suggest what might prevent jTable from refreshing view?

Comment: `Can you suggest what might prevent jTable from refreshing view?` Maybe you have two instances of your JTable. One that you add to the GUI and a second one that you attempt to update the data on. Without a proper `SSCCE` it is all just a wild guess.

Comment: If you want to try out my project it is on github [here](https://github.com/volodiaL/Antivirus)

Comment: @camickr you win the psychic problem solving award today - amazing that you guessed at the root cause on this with the info given - bravo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

camickr is correct, there are actually two instances of your VirusTable (and in fact MainFrame as well, but only one of them is visible) being created. You've provided a way to access the MainFrame object by basically turning it into a singleton, but without the constraint that only one instance can ever be created. IMHO, you could've done this a lot better without creating a static `getInstance` method in your MainFrame class.

Anyhoo, in your main method, you do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

But because of the way you've coded your application, you should be doing this (not that I recommend this approach):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            MainFrame.getInstance().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Thank camickr, not me.

Comment: I cannot see everything! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are making changes to a Swing model from a thread other than the event dispatch thread (hard to tell from your code)?  All Swing interactions must be done from the EDT, so either wrap your table update in SwingUtilities.invokeLater() (if you want it to update as each entry is found) or add the items to the table model in the done() method of SwingWorker which forces the execution on the EDT.

Comment: I update `DefaultTableModel` method is called from `SwingWorker.process` method.